Why do I get 403 - fobidden / StackoverflowError when I implement AuthenticationManager in Java Spring Boot?
I want to implement a login function with spring's in-built authenticationManager-class. I have implemented the code as I (think I) should, but I keep on getting the following error message:
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause
I have understood that the program somewhat gets stuck in a recursive loop, but I don't understand how.
This is my User-class:

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int userId;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String street;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int streetNo;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int zipCode;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String city;

    @ManyToMany // add fetchtypes later
    private Set<Role> roles;

This is my loginDTO:
@Data
public class LoginDTO {

    private String username;
    private String password;
}

This is my method for login in userController:
 @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<String> authenticateUser(@RequestBody LoginDTO loginDTO) {
        return userService.authenticateUser(loginDTO);
    }

This is my method in userService (I have autowired everything that needs to be autowired in the class):
     @Service
    public class UserService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final UserMapper userMapper;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


    @Autowired
    public UserService(
            UserRepository userRepository,
            RoleRepository roleRepository,
            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
            UserMapper userMapper,
            AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.userMapper = userMapper;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }


        public ResponseEntity<String> authenticateUser (LoginDTO loginDTO) {
            try {
                Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginDTO.getUsername(), loginDTO.getPassword()));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                return new ResponseEntity<>(" is successfully logged in.", HttpStatus.OK);

            } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>("Authentication failed: " + ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            }


        }
    }

This is my securityConfig:
I know that CSRF should not be disabled, but for now, until the next step is working properly, I have told spring to disable it.
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .securityContext((context) -> context.requireExplicitSave(false))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS))
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                .requestMatchers(
                        "/api/product/create",
                        "/api/user/logout"
                        ).authenticated()
                .requestMatchers(
                        "/api/user/register",
                        "/api/user/{id}",
                        "/api/category/**",
                        "/api/product/**",
                        "/api/user/login"
                ).permitAll());
    return http.build();
    }

}

I have tried removing the @Data annotation to the user-class as well as the userDTO class and replace it with both allArgsConstructor and noArgsConstructor, but that didn't make any difference.  If i do a system.out.println of the loginDTO in userService, then that works, but the issue seems to be in the next step where I call the authenticationManager and asks it to authenticate the object that I am passing inside of postman, through a POST-request. I know that the user credentials are correct.

could you add also in the code how you are injecting things? not just the method of the classes also the autowired or constructors according to how you are injecting the beans

Hey @GabrielGarcíaGarrido, many thanks for your reply. I have now updated the code so that you can see how I autowire things in my userService-class.
Kind regards, Kimberly

try insteod of this: Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginDTO.getUsername(), loginDTO.getPassword())); doing this: Authentication authentication =
new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginDTO.getUsername(), loginDTO.getPassword())); without the authentication manager. the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken is already an implementation of the Authentication
